# How to stop react component from infinite re-render

Tags: reactjs

I wanna use js-cookie in my app, but the time I get the cookie my component keeps re-rendering until the browser crash.

The error I get is: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition ...

I've just used the shouldComponentUpdate but it caused the click events not working.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) 
{
    return nextState.language != this.state.language;
}
```

Does anybody know any other solution rather than shouldComponentUpdate to stop a component from infinite re-render?

```
class MainLayout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('constructor');
    this.state = {
      sideBarOpen: false,
      languages: getStoreLanguages,
      language: Cookies.get('langCode')
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.langCode();
    this.props.defaultLangCode();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').megaMenu && $('.dropdown-toggle').megaMenu({ container: '.mmd' });
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextState.language != this.state.language;
  }

  toggleSidebar = () => {
    this.setState({
      sideBarOpen: !this.state.sideBarOpen,
    });
  }

  overlayClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      sideBarOpen: false,
    });
  }

  handleLanguage = (langCode) => {
    if (Cookies.get('langCode')) {
      return Cookies.get('langCode');
    } else {
      Cookies.set('langCode', langCode, { expires: 7 });
      return langCode;
    }
  }

  render() {
    let overlay = { display: this.state.sideBarOpen ? 'block' : 'none' };
    const langCode = this.handleLanguage(this.props.params.id);
    const isDefaultLang = isDefaultLanguage(langCode);
    const isValidLang = isValidLanguage(langCode);

    if (langCode && !isValidLang) {
      this.props.router.push(`/${langCode}/error`);
    }

    if (langCode && isValidLang) {
      const path = getLocalisedPath(langCode, isDefaultLang)
      this.props.router.push("/" + path);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet>
          <script type="application/ld+json">{structuredData()}</script>
        </Helmet>
        <TokenManager>
          {(state, methods) => (
            <div>
              <WithHelmet {...this.props} />
              <WithUserHeaderInfo {...this.props} />
              <WithStoreDetail />
              <WithDataLayerStoreDetail />
              <header className='header__nav'>
                <NavbarManagerWillHideOnEditor
                  sideBarOpen={this.state.sideBarOpen}
                  toggleSidebar={this.toggleSidebar}
                  languages={this.state.languages}
                  {...this.props}
                />
                <div
                  className="mmm__overlay"
                  onClick={this.overlayClickHandler}
                  style={overlay}
                />
                <div
                  className="mmm__overlay--hidenav"
                  onClick={this.overlayClickHandler}
                  style={overlay}
                />
              </header>
              <main>{this.props.children}</main>
              <Modal modalId="modal-account" size="md">
                {(closeModal) => (
                  <Auth
                    closeModal={closeModal} />
                )}

              </Modal>
              {!this.props.location.pathname.startsWith('/checkout') && <FooterWillHideOnEditor languages={this.state.languages}/>}
            </div>
          )
          }
        </TokenManager>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, value) => {
  const langCode = Cookies.get('langCode') || value.params.id;
  const defaultLang = getDefaultLanguage();
  const isDefault = isDefaultLanguage(langCode);
  const isValid = isValidLanguage(langCode);
  const lang = !isValid || isDefault ? defaultLang : langCode;

  return {
    langCode: () => dispatch({ type: 'SET_LANGUAGE', payload: lang }),
    defaultLangCode: () => dispatch({ type: 'SET_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE', payload: defaultLang })
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MainLayout);
```

Comment: You need to show how u r updating the state and why.. we can figure out an alternate solution for it. Without it, we can't figure out with the provided  code what is wrong..!

Comment: @Armin : Could you write the general structure of your component here ?

Comment: @Panther I've updated the post with the code. thanks

Comment: @sanji_mika I wrote the code here thanks

Comment: @ArminSaeedi : I have one question : Which cause make your component infinite re-render ? I've seen that you used setState for "sideBarOpen", but not for the state "language", where you setState for "language" and which cause for infinite re-render, please ?

Comment: @sanji_mika I initialized the language in constructor that's why there is no setState for that, actually the issue happens when I added the cookie, I'm not sure exactly which one cause the re-render

Comment: @ArminSaeedi what is the getStoreLanguages ? I have doute in it...
For checking which cause for render, in shouldComponentUpdate, you will write three different conditions regarding to three states values. Ex : if (nextState.languages != this.state.language) console.log(1); => Check which cause made re-render, it's very important for revolving problme.

Comment: @sanji_mika Let me clarify more on this, actually infinite re-render stopped once I added the shouldComponentUpdate but now no click events works, I'm looking for two solutions:
1- Either write a condition in shouldComponentIUpdate to let other events render the component.
2- Or I fix the infinite re-render without using shouldComponentUpdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let overlay = { display: this.state.sideBarOpen ? 'block' : 'none' };
const langCode = this.handleLanguage(this.props.params.id);
const isDefaultLang = isDefaultLanguage(langCode);
const isValidLang = isValidLanguage(langCode);

if (langCode && !isValidLang) {
  this.props.router.push(`/${langCode}/error`);
}

if (langCode && isValidLang) {
  const path = getLocalisedPath(langCode, isDefaultLang)
  this.props.router.push("/" + path);
}
```

Here the code is resetting the state/ or mapDispatchToProps dispatched again .that's why it's rerendering.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why component keep re-rendering, actually it was because of the condition in:

```
if (langCode && isValidLang) {
    const path = getLocalisedPath(langCode, isDefaultLang)
    this.props.router.push("/" + path);
}
```

which is always true and gets the path and push to the route which cause the component re-render.

Thanks

Comment: Congrats ! I said you finding which cause made re-render anormal, it's very important for revolving this problem like that. Afterward, you must find the principal cause firstly (by console.log() for example), not blocking re-render in shouldComponentUpdate and not understanding the problem.